# NDK performance

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've just started to play around with NDK to explore the sweet performance boost that I've been promised. To get a feel for the difference, I tried a dumb number-crunching task (render a Mandelbrot set to a bitmap) and compared it to a Java version of the same code. To my big surprise, the C version is significantly slower (5.0 seconds vs 1.6 on my HTC One, on average). Even stranger, the cost isn't because of the overhead of making a native call, but it's the actual number-crunching that takes longer.

This can't be right, can it? What did I miss?

C version (debug timer code removed):

```
const int MAX_ITER = 63;
const float MAX_DEPTH = 16;

static uint16_t rgb565(int red, int green, int blue)
{
    return (uint16_t)(((red << 8) & 0xf800) | ((green << 2) & 0x03e0) | ((blue  >> 3) & 0x001f));
}

float zAbs(float re, float im) {
    return re*re + im*im;
}

int depth(float cRe, float cIm) {
    int i=0;
    float re, im;
    float zRe = 0.0f;
    float zIm = 0.0f;
    while ((zAbs(zRe, zIm) < MAX_DEPTH) && (i < MAX_ITER)) {
        re = zRe * zRe - zIm * zIm + cRe;
        im = 2.0f * zRe * zIm + cIm;
        zRe = re;
        zIm = im;
        i++;
    }
  return i;
}

extern "C"
void Java_com_example_ndktest_MainActivity_renderFractal(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject bitmap, float re0, float im0, float b)
{
    AndroidBitmapInfo info;
    void* pixels;
    int ret;

    long t0 = currentTimeInMilliseconds();

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return;
    }

    if (info.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565) {
        LOGE("Bitmap format is not RGB_565 !");
        return;
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    }


    int w = info.width;
    int h = info.height;

    float re, im;
    int z = 0;
    uint16_t*  px = (uint16_t*)pixels;
    for(int y=0; y<h; y++) {
        im = im0 + b*((float)y/(float)h);
        for(int x=0; x<info.width; x++) {
            re = re0 + b*((float)x/(float)w);
            z = depth(re, im);
            px[y*w + x] = rgb565(0, z*4, z * 16);
        }
    }

    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
}
```

Java version:

```
    private static final int MAX_ITER = 63;
    private static final float MAX_DEPTH = 16;

    static int rgb565(int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        return ((red << 8) & 0xf800) | ((green << 2) & 0x03e0) | ((blue >> 3) & 0x001f);
    }

    static float zAbs(float re, float im) {
        return re*re + im*im;
    }

    static int depth(float cRe, float cIm) {
        int i=0;
        float re, im;
        float zRe = 0.0f;
        float zIm = 0.0f;
        while ((zAbs(zRe, zIm) < MAX_DEPTH) && (i < MAX_ITER)) {
            re = zRe * zRe - zIm * zIm + cRe;
            im = 2.0f * zRe * zIm + cIm;
            zRe = re;
            zIm = im;
            i++;
        }
      return i;
    }

    static void renderFractal(Bitmap bitmap, float re0, float im0, float b)
    {
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] pixels = new int[w * h];

        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        float re, im;
        int z = 0;      
        for(int y=0; y<h; y++) {
            im = im0 + b*((float)y/(float)h);
            for(int x=0; x<w; x++) {
                re = re0 + b*((float)x/(float)w);
                z = depth(re, im);
                pixels[y*w + x] = rgb565(0, z*4, z * 16);
            }
        }

        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you're building for the armeabi-v7a target.  If you build for the armeabi target, you'll be using software floating point calculations in the NDK version.

Comment: Thank you fadden. That made a HUGE difference (dropped to 0.7 sec!).

Comment: I had a feeling. :-)  I'll put that in the answer field and add a couple of notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this was because the NDK code was built for the armeabi target rather than the armeabi-v7a target.  The former is intended to work across a broad range of hardware, including devices without floating-point hardware, so it does all floating-point calculations in software.

Building for armeabi-v7a enables the VFP instructions, so anything that relies heavily on floating point calculations will speed up dramatically.

If you build exclusively for armeabi-v7a, you will exclude a fairly broad selection of devices, even relatively recent ones (e.g. the Samsung Galaxy Ace).  These devices have VFP support, but the CPU is based on the ARMv6 instruction set rather than ARMv7.  There is no "pre-ARMv7 CPU with VFP" build target, so you have to build for armeabi, or use custom build rules and careful selection of supported devices.

At the other end of the spectrum, you may get a small performance boost by specifying hard-float ABI within your armeabi-v7a library (`-mhard-float` -- requires NDK r9b).

FWIW, one of the selling points of just-in-time compilers like the one in Dalvik is that they can recognize the system capabilities and adapt code generation appropriately.

Comment: Thank you again, that was also very clarifying. (Googling wildly as we speak...). Seems I have a lot to learn about low-level Android. 

As mentioned, I'm just exploring right now and don't mind if most devices are excluded.

Comment: If any future googler wonders, you build for armeabi-v7a by adding a line to the jni/Application.mk file (if it doesn't exist, create it):


    APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a